# Vuejs loading CSS and JS files giving MIME type error

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have created a new vue-webpack project. when I want to add CSS and js files through `link` and `script` it gives me this error `The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/src/assets/styles.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`
and for js files, it gives this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`
I have included them inside `index.html` file.

I used to work like this, but now at this time, I am facing this.

css file:

```
body {background:black;}
```

js file:

```
console.log('hello world')
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>myapp</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./src/assets/form.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: by the way adding type="text/css" or type="text/javascript" does not works.

Comment: But i used to like this, and i tried to import them inside main.js but for bootstrap it couldn't find jquery even i imported jquery above bootstrap.

Comment: It might be an error in the path of the file, it returns an 404 error that returns an HTML file, that's why the error says you got a '<', please, verify that the URL of your files are correct

Comment: No the path is correct. the guides can verify the path correctly.

Comment: Exactly what sort of project is this? How did you create it?

Comment: vue init webpack myapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing the assets from main.js solved the problem.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do it? as i am facing the same issue and googling the error from 3 days... i am new to vuejs

Answer (score 0):

First, I strongly suggest you stop using the old Vue CLI v2 and update to the [latest version](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

```sh
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

---

If you want to include some extra JS, CSS or other files that are not part of the Webpack bundle, you need to move them into the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

```
- public
  - index.html
  - favicon.ico
  - form.js
  - styles.css
```

and reference them like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>styles.css">
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>form.js"></script>
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html

Comment: I don't see any folder named public